# Error code in LaTeX

Tags: errors

I have got the following error code:

```
"file ended while scanning use of \document"
```

I dont know what to do with it.

Regards,

Gabor Luko

Comment: Try to reduce your code to a minimum code that reproduce the problem. Then edit your post with this code included and you will have possibilities to find help. Now you don't really have.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a complete minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)) that begins at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` that reproduces the error/issue you're facing.

Comment: the standard `\document` command will not give that error, even if used incorrectly so you must have a non standard definition of the command.

Answer (score 3):

A file that just contains the lines

```
\renewcommand\document[1]{}
\document
```

produces the error message

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \document.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

Because the command is defined to have an argument such as `\document{hello}` but the file ends with no argument after `\document`.

But `\document` is the core latex command which is the definition of
`\begin{document}`
as used in every LaTeX document, that command should not be redefined to take an argument.